# Why do some methods of integration converge faster than others?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Why do some methods of integration converge faster than others?

I was recently examining various methods of integration such as

- the trapezoid rule,
- Simpson's rule and
- the rectangular formula.

I learned that Simpson's rule converges the fastest. But why? Is it just because dividing an interval of a function into parabolas is better than rectangles and trapezoids?

Comment: Thank you for the neat edit @Klangen!

Comment: Intuitively put, constants $\subset$ linear functions $\subset$ quadratics, and each approximates the functions more accurately than the previous. Better approximation implies faster convergence.

Comment: An analogy with Taylor's theorem may help: loosely speaking Simpson's rule is like integrating quadratic Taylor polynomials on each subinterval, the trapezoidal rule is like integrating linear Taylor polynomials on each subinterval, and the rectangle rule is like integrating constant Taylor polynomials on each subinterval. For smooth enough functions and fine enough meshes, more Taylor terms = smaller error. However, this view does not explain a certain very interesting situation, namely the case of periodic smooth functions, in which the trapezoidal rule performs better than expected.

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what is meant by that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simpson integrates polynomials upto degree $3$ exact, the other methods arrive only at degree $1$

Therefore Simpson is much more accurate if the same nodes are used.

Comment: You're right. Simpson's takes degree 3 polynomials correctly. I just didn't think far enough ahead. The rectangular method depends on whether you evaluate the function at the midpoints of the intervals or at the end points. Midpoints makes it basically on par with trapezoid (tackling degree 1 polynomials). End points makes it horrible.